# Sympy conversion between piecewise and min/max functions

Tags: sympy

Is there a way to convert min/max to piecewise functions and vice versa? For example:

```
x = Symbol('x')

Min(Max(x, 0), 1)
```

Is the same as the piecewise function:

```
⎧0      for x < 0    
⎪                    
⎨x      for x > 0 ∧ x < 1
⎪                    
⎩1      for x > 1
```

With sympy you can write this as:

```
Piecewise(
     (0, x < 0),
     (x, (x > 0) & (x < 1)),
     (1, x > 1)
)
```

There is probably a mathematical term for this which I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can go from Min/Max to Piecewise using rewrite but I'm not sure how to go the other way (maybe not implemented yet):

```
In [15]: e = Min(Max(x, 0), 1)

In [16]: e
Out[16]: Min(1, Max(0, x))

In [17]: e.rewrite(Piecewise)
Out[17]: 
⎧      1        for x ≥ 1
⎪                        
⎨⎧0  for x ≤ 0           
⎪⎨              otherwise
⎩⎩x  otherwise           

In [18]: piecewise_fold(_)
Out[18]: 
⎧1  for x ≥ 1
⎪            
⎨0  for x ≤ 0
⎪            
⎩x  otherwise
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#rewrite
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.rewrite